# MATLAB Stop calculation and replace it by another calculation on button press

Tags: matlab, timer, interrupt

I am working on a GUI that accomplishes clustering analysis of data. I have been asked to add the possibility of skipping the clustering step since it can be lengthy, so I integrated a pushbutton with a callback function that accomplished alternate calculations (treatment of the data without the clustering). However, the way I coded it (the only way I could think of), the clustering step can only be skipped when the program is in one of the `waitfor` loop waiting for a user input; once the clustering calculation has been launched, the button doesn't work anymore.

Is there a way I could use such a pushbutton, with its corresponding callback function, to stop the ongoing computation and replace it with alternate operations? I have heard about timers, but even after reading the `timer` MATLAB documentation I am still at loss as how to use them... Could I monitor the status of the button (or of any variable) to accomplish that?

Comment: Can you post some codes of the callback for clustering? It'll be easier for people to figure out how to help you.

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum you'd need a shared state that would let you indicate to your function that you want to cancel.

You can do it by global variable or other mechanism. A cleaner way is is using classes. See an example below:

*Token.m:*

```
classdef Token < handle
    properties
        Cancel = false;
    end    
end
```

*longrunningop.m:*

```
function longrunningop(token)

% your long operation goes there...
for i=1:1000
    disp('step '), i
    pause(0.5)

    if token.Cancel
        return
    end
end
```

*Test script:*

```
token = Token;

btn = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'Start',...
    'Position', [20 50 50 20],...
    'Callback', @(a,b) longrunningop(token));   


btn = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'Cancel',...
    'Position', [20 20 50 20],...
    'Callback',  'token.Cancel = true;');
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. My problem comes mainly from the fact that I did not write the long operation; the script that takes a long time to execute is the MATLAB native function `fitgmdist`, which I use prior to using the `pca` function. I don't think I can modify that script to had a `return` somewhere in it... I did something similar to what you wrote in my main function, using the 'Tag' property of an object, but I can only implant it outside the long calculation, which makes it less useful.